# Call App.component.ts method from another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a "signup" method on app.component.ts class which is being called from "Sign up" link on app.component.html file. It internally calls a service class  and some more login in it.

html:

```
<a (click)="signup($event)">Sign up</a>
```

ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
       signup(e: any) {
            this.service.signup();
       }

}
```

There is another html/component file which has the same signup link. Is it possible to call AppComponent's signup method directly from the html/component file?

Comment: Use an observable, subscribe to it in `AppComponent` and emit events from the other component.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you have an example code? (I am new to A2)

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: thanks - The other component is directly accessed from routing component (i.e. it does not have a selector). Will it still work?

Comment: It will still work. A shared service doesn't depend in any way on selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call one component method/function in below conditions

- Both component should be in same DOM mean both have parent child relation.
- You can shared main component across other component
- Make shared service.
- Suscribe event on any property/value change. Event Emitter.

Better to use shared service for your requirement, where common function are together.